# Angular2 RC BaseRequestOption Constructor Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, constructor, angular

I don’t know whether I am missing something but injecting the constructor of a custom baserequestoptions class was working fine for me in Beta 17 but after moving to RC1 this approach doesn’t seem to work any more.

I have created a plunkr to illustrate that the webapibaseurl now comes through as undefined (the same code approach but with Beta 17 references worked):

https://embed.plnkr.co/usOljRDLap9RlLd3RIBd/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This still works for me. Here is the custom option class I used:

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs} from '@angular/http';

export class AppRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
  constructor() {
  }

  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = 'https://www.test.org' + options.url;
    return super.merge(options);
  }
}
```

and I register it this way:

```
bootstrap(App, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: AppRequestOptions})
]);
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/MK30JR2qK8aJIGwNqMZ5?p=preview.

**Edit**

It seems that there is a problem at the level of dependency injection for such class. I opened an issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8925.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  The options class itself is fine and working on requests however the key thing for me is trying to inject 'webApiBaseUrl' (or anything else for that matter) which is coming through as 'undefined'.

Comment: @Monkeeman69 Wouah, you're completely right. It seems that the dependency injection doesn't work on classes that extend the `BaseRequestOptions` one... Whereas the injection (of `webApiBaseUrl`) is possible somewhere else. I think that it's a bug / regression. I'll open a bug for this.

Answer (score 4):

Extending from `RequestOptions` instead of from `BaseRequestOptions` made it work for me

```ts
@Injectable()
export class AppRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {
  constructor(@Inject('webApiBaseUrl') private webApiBaseUrl:string) {
    super({method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: new Headers()});
    console.log('webApiBaseUrl', webApiBaseUrl);
  }

  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
    options.url = this.webApiBaseUrl + options.url;
    console.log('merge - options.url = '+options.url);
    return super.merge(options);
  }
}
```

otherwise for some unknown reason injecting `@Inject('webApiBaseUrl') private webApiBaseUrl:string` didn't work.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/UgKw8OV9jM6gXtSDvwiM?p=preview)