# Unexpected behaviour with extended BaseRequestOptions in Angular2 App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, csrf-protection

I have an angular2 app which communicates with an ASP.Net MVC backend.
The backend requires an `AntiForgeryToken` to be present on `POST` requests.

For this, my `index.html` is served with a hidden input where its value represents the token. I guess this is a common approach in an `ASP.Net MVC` project (not topic of this question).

Now to grab this token and use it in my request headers i extended `BaseRequestOptions` in my main.ts like this:

```
@Injectable()
class AntiForgeryRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
        let xsrfElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
        if (xsrfElement) {
            let xsrfToken:string = xsrfElement.value;
            this.headers.append('X-XSRF-Token', xsrfToken);
        }
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```

and provided it as `RequestOptions` like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ...
    provide(RequestOptions, {useClass: AntiForgeryRequestOptions}),
    ...
]);
```

With this set up, i can make `POST`-requests in my services like this:

```
post(url:string, body:any):Observable<any> {
        let options = new RequestOptions();

        return this._http.post(url, body, options)
            .map((response:any) => {
                ...
            })
            .catch(this._handleError);
    }
```

which works fine. The `POST` works and the `CSRF Token` is send with it.

---

### The Problem

Today i had to adjust this, because i have to switch out the Token on some occassions and experienced some weird behaviour i can't explain:

In my understanding as soon as i do this: `let options = new RequestOptions()` the constructor of `AntiForgeryRequestOptions` should have been called and headers should be set for this `RequestOptions` i just creatd. But if i do a `console.log(options)` directly after the call, i see that all properties are `NULL` even the headers. (It still works, the `CSRF Token` is send, its `content-type` is `application/json`) but i can't access it or change it for the coming request.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening or how i would alter my previously defined `RequestOptions` in the constructor of my `AntiForgeryRequestOptions`?

---

### Additional information:

There was a reason why i did it that way. When i started this project, angular2 was still in beta state (now i'm working with angular2 rc1). At that time there was an issue with `CSRF Tokens` where you can't set it directly in your options. Now with the new version i would not need to provide a custom `AntiForgeryRequestOptions`. I could leave that away and just do it like this in the post requests:

```
post(url:string, body:any):Observable<any> {
        let options = new RequestOptions();
        options.headers = new Headers();
        let xsrfElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
        if (xsrfElement) {
            let xsrfToken:string = xsrfElement.value;
            options.headers.append('X-XSRF-Token', xsrfToken);
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        ...
    }
```

---

### Solution

As Günther suggested in his comment, i have to use `merge` in my custom `AntiForgeryRequestOptions` like this:

```
@Injectable()
class AntiForgeryRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
        options.headers = new Headers();
        let xsrfElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
        if (xsrfElement) {
            let xsrfToken:string = xsrfElement.value;
            options.headers.append('X-XSRF-Token', xsrfToken);
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return super.merge(options);
    }
}
```

which works. Now everytime i call `new RequestOptions()` the `Headers` property is updated correctly, which means whenever i change the value of my hidden input field for the CSRF Token, the headers will adjust like they should.

Comment: I think you need to add `merge()` like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549599/angular2-rc-baserequestoption-constructor-injection/37550368#37550368

Comment: Thank you, that's working. i adjusted my question. if you want, you can use it to provide a "real" answer. Still, don't really understand why because calling `new RequestOptions()` should call this constructor..maybe someone will provide more information for this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom `merge(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptions { ... }` method because the default implementation just checks if headers were passed to `merge(...)` and then takes these or otherwise takes the headers of the current `AntiForgeryRequestOptions` instance but id doesn't actually merge.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/f39c9c9e75671a7e235734b6b8aef263f6dff254/modules/%40angular/http/src/base_request_options.ts#L101

Example (from the question - thanks for the permission)

```
@Injectable()
class AntiForgeryRequestOptions extends BaseRequestOptions {
    constructor () {
        super();
    }

    merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {
        options.headers = new Headers();
        let xsrfElement = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]');
        if (xsrfElement) {
            let xsrfToken:string = xsrfElement.value;
            options.headers.append('X-XSRF-Token', xsrfToken);
        }
        options.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return super.merge(options);
    }
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/37550368/217408